# Drawing Circle on Map around current location and showing only markers from that circle rather than outside circle in android

Tags: java, android

I was able to draw circle on map around my current location but I want to  show the markers  only inside that circle and hide other markers from map.

Answer (score 2):

You need to first **draw a circle** and then compare each **marker** either it is **inside** or outside circle, by using this method.

```
private void checkCircle(){
    float[] distance = new float[2];

    Location.distanceBetween(marker_latitude, marker_longitude,
            circle.getCenter().latitude, circle.getCenter().longitude, distance);

    if(distance[0] > circle.getRadius()  ){
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Outside", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Inside", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

If you are getting that your **marker** is in outside than dont need to add in map.